# Running Rsync Command Inside Expect Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rsync, expect

I have the following expect script that uses rsync and expect to automate the process.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
rsync -a --progress --delete --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh' root@00.00.00.00:/var/www/test/ /var/www/test
expect "password:"
send "XXXXX";
interact
```

However the rsync command of course does not work inside the expect script. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Solved! Adding "spawn " before rsync solves the issue.

Comment: You should at this as an answer so that others can clearly see it ;).

Answer (score 1):

As Raphael has realized 'Adding "spawn " before rsync solves the issue'

Good catch!